# How can I choose the wights of CrossEntropy loss?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, image-segmentation, cross-entropy

I am dealing with a semantic segmentation model which classifies each pixel in 3 classes: background, liver and tumor. I am using the classic UNET architecture with CrossEntropyLoss from the PyTorch implementation.

Since the dataset is imbalance having a lot of images (slices) containing only background and liver class, I decided to use weights in my loss function in order to make my model to tackle the imbalance class issue.

Concretely, my weights are chosen in the following way: [0.001, 1, 5] -> (background, liver, tumor).

My question is: having in mind that my current approach is a naive one, how can I find a better way on initialize the weights? Is there a best practice?

Thank you!

Comment: You could also consider the following losses that are often used in semantic segmentation: Dice, Tversky, Focal.

Comment: @jkr The question targets the cross-entropy loss, specifically and does not suggest introducing a different loss function altogether. Even so, cross-entropy is *very* widespread for semantic segmentation.

Answer (score 0):

Informally, think of *classes* and *pixels*. If the weights are all equal to one, you make the model “care” about pixels equally and about the classes proportionally to their frequency. If you make them inversely proportional to class frequencies, it will care about classes equally but unequally about pixels.

Think if for your application it is more important to detect the tumor overall, or to classify a given pixels correctly.

More formally, the weights adjust the prior (in Bayesian sense) you want your model to have for each given pixel, between data frequencies and uniform.

Comment: I would say, in my case, the scope is to have a better precision on classifying the tumor class

Comment: I'm giving you the two reference points (equal weights and inverse-data-frequency weights) to contextualize whatever weights you have chosen for your task. Be aware, however, that although increasing the weights on tumor will make the network less likely to *miss* the tumor, it will also make it more likely to falsely detect it (it's just biased towards seeing it more often). This is a fundamental trade-off of precision and recall (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall).